# laravel model select without Attribute function

Tags: php, laravel, model

I use laravel model to select some data like this

```
$query->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'preferred_name', 'app_status'])

public function getAppStatusAttribute()
{
  if ($this->attributes['app_status'] == -1 || 
      $this->attributes['app_status'] >= count($this->app_status_list))
         return "";
      else
         return $this->app_status_list[$this->app_status];
}
```

In laravel model, it will auto select `AppStatus` from `getAppStatusAttribute()`,

How to select the raw data without `getAppStatusAttribute()` in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the mutated and the original value, I suggest you give it a different name. For example, call your function `getAppStatusStringAttribute`, then you can access the original data as usual and get the mutated attribute with `->appStatusString`.